# Apache Flink : filtering based on previous value

Tags: java, stream, apache-flink, stream-processing

All filtering examples in apache flink documentation display simple cases of filtering according to a global threshold.

But what if filtering on an entry should take into account the previous entry?

Let's say we have a stream of sensor data. We need to discard the current sensor data entry if it's X% larger than then previous entry.

Is there a simple solution for this? Either in Apache Flink or in plain Java.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flink, this can be done with state.

Your use case is very similar to the [fraud detection example](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/try-flink/datastream_api.html) from flink doc.

Comment: Thanks! Fraud Detection example actually helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

State is the enabler that makes this possible, but you also need to pay attention to the definition of "previous entry". If event ingestion order it all that matters, then this is easily implemented as a RichFilterFunction or a RichFlatMapFunction. But if "previous entry" needs to take per-event timestamps into account then this becomes more challenging because you need to first sort the stream by timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The truth is that the entries are pre-sorted according to timestamp so the order is not an issue.